# What Permissions are Required for Google Admob and Firebase with Analytics?

Tags: android, admob, android-permissions, google-analytics-firebase

I'm new to developing android apps, and this is my first one that I'm about to publish. The last step for me is adding permissions. I have to add permissions manually as I'm building the app through Phonegap. Anyway, I can't find what the specific permissions are required to ask of the user if you are going to use Firebase with Google Analytics and Google Admob. My app doesn't need any other permissions than for these services. (By the way, I am not adding these services via SDK, I am adding my app to these services online. However, I believe I still need to add app permissions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only internet, you can add it in your `Manifest`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

No need for runtime permissions for internet.

Comment: Really? No need to ask for device info or anything else for the ads or analytics?

Comment: Nope, just internet is all you need.

Comment: Well, thank you very much! This was holding me from being able to publish the app because I didn't want to violate Google's conditions for user privacy and such.